# Python Code line by line meaning

Tags: python, list

I have got a code and need to get the line by line meaning of this python code.

```
marksheet = []
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    marksheet.append([raw_input(), float(input())])

second_highest = sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])))[1]
print('\n'.join([a for a,b in sorted(marksheet) if b == second_highest]))
```

Comment: Give it your best shot and tell us what you think it means. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: `second_highest` is actually `second_lowest`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend you to go through the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Just for your understanding of this code, I've added the comments.

```
#initialising an empty list!
marksheet = [] 

#iterating through a for loop starting from zero, to some user input(default type string) - that is converted to int
for i in range(0,int(input())): 
    #appending user input(some string) and another user input(a float value) as a list to marksheet
    marksheet.append([raw_input(), float(input())]) 

#[marks for name, marks in marksheet] - get all marks from list
#set([marks for name, marks in marksheet]) - getting unique marks
#list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])) - converting it back to list
#sorting the result in decending order with reverse=True and getting the value as first index which would be the second largest.
second_highest = sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])),reverse=True)[1] 

#printing the name and mark of student that has the second largest mark by iterating through the sorted list.
#If the condition matches, the result list is appended to tuple  -`[a for a,b in sorted(marksheet) if b == second_highest])` 
#now join the list with \n - newline to print name and mark of student with second largest mark
print('\n'.join([a for a,b in sorted(marksheet) if b == second_highest]))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot only the 2nd last line was a problem, i have understood it thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Would do this in a comment but I don't have 50 reputation yet:

You don't need to use sorted on second_highest but apparently it is not a good habit to rely on this so you can keep the sorted. Calling sorted on an already sorted list doesn't use a lot of resources anyway.

```
second_highest = sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])))[1]
```

Also if the list contains something like [1,3,2,5,3,2,1] it will give 2 as result and not 1 since a set removes all duplicates.

If you want to keep duplicates use:

```
second_highest = sorted([marks for name, marks in marksheet]))[1]
```

Comment: _"You don't need to use sorted on second_highest since it converts it first in a set and a set is always sorted"_ This is simply not true. Sets are unsorted per definition and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). You're right in the sense that due to how sets are implemented, things like `list({3,2,1})` will result in `[1,2,3]`, but that's not something you should rely on. You should _definitely_ explicitly sort the list.